# Maven tomcat:run plugin and datasource configuration via JNDI

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I am trying to configure DB DataSource by using Spring JndiObjectFactoryBean, so, i have tomcat:run plugin for local test purposes and context.xml file located in src/test/resources/maven-tomcat-plugin/

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <contextFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/maven-tomcat-plugin/context.xml</contextFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/MyLocalDB" global="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" global="jdbc/MyDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc" username="" password="" maxActive="100" maxIdle="20" minIdle="5"
    maxWait="10000" />
</Context>
```

but i have: Name [jdbc/TestDB] is not bound in this Context

It looks like contextPath gives nothing.

Does anyone have any idia how to solve it?

Comment: I dont know how, but i removed ResourceLink and have used jndi name jdbc/MyDB and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ResourceLink>` element is intended to construct a link to a **Global** resource which should be declared under your `server.xml` file and which might look as below:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource name="jdbc/DatabaseName" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="dbUsername" password="dbPasswd"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
          maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
</GlobalNamingResources/>
```

***Note that the `name` attribute must match the `global` attribute of your ResourceLink element.***

So either declare a matching global resource, or just remove the Resource Link and use the declared resources as you did.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following configuration (don't forget add the dependency item):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>9090</port>
        <path>/myapp</path>
        <contextFile>${basedir}/tomcat7-maven-plugin/context.xml</contextFile>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And the context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context debug="true" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"
    antiJARLocking="true">  
    <Resource name="jdbc/myDS" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30"
      maxWait="10000" validationQuery="select sysdate from dual"
      username="userdb" password="pass123"
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:sid" />
</Context>
```

For mor info you could check Apache Tomcat webpage https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html